# Issue while deleting a cartItem in realm

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, realm

In this view if I tried to send another view like CartItem() then the app get crash and the error Thread 1: "Object has been deleted or invalidated." if I again get into the app the cartitem is deleted!
I think object is some where in use

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class ApiResponse: Decodable {
    let status: Bool
    let page: String
    let category: String
    let results: [Product]
}

class Product: Object, Identifiable, Decodable {
    @Persisted var product_id: String
    @Persisted var product_name: String
    @Persisted var product_price: String
    @Persisted var product_group: String
    @Persisted var product_description: String
    @Persisted var product_thumb_images: String
    @Persisted var product_big_images: String
    @Persisted var isInCart: Bool = false
//    @Persisted var quantity: Int = 1 // Default quantity is 1

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case product_id, product_name, product_price, product_group, product_description, product_thumb_images, product_big_images
    }
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "product_id"
    }
}

class CartItem: Object,Identifiable {
    @Persisted var product: Product?
    @Persisted var quantity: Int = 1

    convenience init(product: Product, quantity: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.product = product
        self.quantity = quantity
    }
}

import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift
import Realm

class ProductViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var products: [Product]?
    @Published var errorMessage: String?
    @Published var cartItems: [CartItem] = []
    @Published var selectedCategory: String = "All"

    internal func fetch() {
        let urlString: String
        if selectedCategory == "All" {
            urlString = ""
        } else {
            urlString = ""
        }
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            self.errorMessage = "Invalid URL"
            return
        }

        AF.request(url)
            .validate()
            .responseDecodable(of: ApiResponse.self) { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let apiResponse):
                    self.products = apiResponse.results
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.errorMessage = "Error fetching data: \(error)"
                }
            }
    }

    func addToCart(product: Product) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()

            if let existingProduct = realm.object(ofType: Product.self, forPrimaryKey: product.product_id) {
                try realm.write {
                    if existingProduct.isInCart {
                        if let existingCartItem = cartItems.first(where: { $0.product?.product_id == product.product_id }) {
                            existingCartItem.quantity += 1
                        } else {
                            // Create a new CartItem with quantity 1
                            let cartItem = CartItem(product: existingProduct, quantity: 1)
                            realm.add(cartItem)
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Update the isInCart property and add to cart
                        existingProduct.isInCart = true
                        // Create a new CartItem with quantity 1
                        let cartItem = CartItem(product: existingProduct, quantity: 1)
                        realm.add(cartItem)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Product does not exist in the database, handle accordingly
                // Create a new CartItem with quantity 1
                let cartItem = CartItem(product: product, quantity: 1)
                try realm.write {
                    realm.add(cartItem)
                }
            }

            updateCartItems()
        } catch {
            print("Error adding to cart: \(error)")
        }
    }



    func removeFromCart(product: Product) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            if let existingCartItem = cartItems.first(where: { $0.product?.product_id == product.product_id }) {
                if existingCartItem.quantity > 1 {
                    try realm.write {
                        existingCartItem.quantity -= 1
                    }
                } else {
                    // Update the isInCart property and remove from cart
                    if let existingProduct = existingCartItem.product {
                        try realm.write {
                            existingProduct.isInCart = false
                        }
                    }
                    try realm.write {
                        realm.delete(existingCartItem)
                    }
                }
                updateCartItems()
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error removing from cart: \(error)")
        }
    }


    internal func updateCartItems() {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            cartItems = Array(realm.objects(CartItem.self))
        } catch {
            print("Error updating cart items: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func calculateTotalPrice() -> Double {
        return cartItems.reduce(0) { $0 + Double($1.quantity) * Double($1.product?.product_price ?? "0")! }
    }
}

//
//  AddCartView.swift
//  ZED_Shop
//
//  Created by JARVIS on 22/12/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct AddCartView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ProductViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if viewModel.cartItems.isEmpty {
                    Text("Your cart is empty.")
                } else {
                    List {
                        ForEach(viewModel.cartItems) { cartItem in
                            VStack() {
                                HStack {
                                    VStack{
                                        Text(cartItem.product?.product_name ?? "Unknown Product")
                                            .font(.smallCaps(.title3)())
                                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                            .padding(.top)
                                            .padding(.leading)
                                        Text("\(cartItem.product?.product_price ?? "0")")
                                            .font(.title)
                                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                            .padding(.leading)
                                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                        Text("\(cartItem.quantity)")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .padding(.bottom)
                                    }
                                    Spacer()
                                    HStack{
                                        RemoteImage(url: URL(string: cartItem.product!.product_thumb_images))
                                            .frame(width: 130, height: 170)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                            viewModel.removeFromCart(product: viewModel.cartItems[indexSet.first!].product!)
                        })
                    }
                }

                Text("Total Price: \(viewModel.calculateTotalPrice())")

                Button("Checkout") {
                    // Handle checkout logic
                }
                .disabled(viewModel.cartItems.isEmpty)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Cart")
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.updateCartItems() // Fetch cart items on appear
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddCartView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        return AddCartView(viewModel: ProductViewModel())
    }
}

import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct CartItemView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ProductViewModel
    let cartItem: CartItem
    let product: Product
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Text(cartItem.product?.product_name ?? "Unknown Product")
                        .font(.smallCaps(.title3)())
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.top)
                        .padding(.leading)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        // Handle delete action
                        withAnimation {
                            viewModel.removeFromCart(product: cartItem.product!)
                        }                 }) {
                            Image(systemName: "trash")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                        .padding(.top)
                        .padding(.trailing)
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                Text("₹\(String(format: "%.2f", viewModel.calculateTotalPrice()))")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        // Decrease quantity action

                    }) {
                        Text("-")
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .background(.blue.opacity(0.1))
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("\(cartItem.quantity)")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        // Increase quantity action
                    }) {
                        Text("+")
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .background(.blue.opacity(0.1))
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: 200)
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 170)
            
            RemoteImage(url: URL(string: cartItem.product!.product_thumb_images))
                .frame(width: 130, height: 170)
                .frame(alignment: .trailing)
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 170)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 2)
        .padding(.leading)
        .padding(.trailing)
    }

}
```

Please give me solution for this issue

I want to CartItem in AddtoCartView like

```
struct AddCartView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ProductViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if viewModel.cartItems.isEmpty {
                    Text("Your cart is empty.")
                } else {
                    List {
                        ForEach(viewModel.cartItems) { cartItem in
                            VStack() {
                                CartItemView(
                                    viewModel:viewModel,
                                    cartItem: cartItem, product: cartItem.product!
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                            viewModel.removeFromCart(product: viewModel.cartItems[indexSet.first!].product!)
                        })
                    }
                }

                Text("Total Price: \(viewModel.calculateTotalPrice())")

                Button("Checkout") {
                    // Handle checkout logic
                }
                .disabled(viewModel.cartItems.isEmpty)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Cart")
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.updateCartItems() // Fetch cart items on appear
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddCartView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        return AddCartView(viewModel: ProductViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is SwiftUI you shouldn't have view model objects, that is the job of the `View` struct hierarchy. State should be decentralised across small `View` structs with lets for read only or @Binding for read/write, you shouldn't have `@ObservedObject` in every `View` that will slow it down to a crawl and maybe why it is crashing. Try renaming and splitting `ProductViewModel` into `ProductFetcher` / `CartFetcher` and only include fetch code and remove all view data out of it, e.g. like the `selectedCategory`.

Comment: Yeah! I made the changes, that's work too, Thank You for your answer

Comment: Great I copied it into an answer

Comment: I would add the core reason the code is crashing is due to casting Realm objects to a Swift array here `cartItems = Array(realm.objects(CartItem.self))`. Then what's happening as an object is updated, deleted etc, the .reduce is crashing because that object's reference is no longer valid (nil element in the array). So best bet is to not do that.. use Realm constructs such as Results and RealmSwift.List when dealing with Realm and those oddball issues generally go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is SwiftUI you shouldn't have view model objects, that is the job of the View struct hierarchy. State should be decentralised across small View structs with lets for read only or `@Binding` for read/write, you shouldn't have `@ObservedObject` in every View that will slow it down to a crawl and maybe why it is crashing. Try renaming and splitting `ProductViewModel` into `ProductFetcher` / `CartFetcher` and only include fetch code and remove all view data out of it, e.g. like the `selectedCategory`.

Comment: See my comment to the question for the cause of the crash. Good answer btw.